# Trouble installing tensorflow on linux

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am having trouble while importing tensorflow in vs code in ubuntu linux. I have installed it using pip(my cpu is intel pentium g2020) and this is what I get after`import tensorflow as tf` and I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBcN.png)

also my tensorflow version is 2.7

and python version is 2.7.18

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your env is incompatible. you can try to create a virtual env for your code ,such as :

```
conda create -n yourname_env
```